# Find all tables with a field containing xml string values

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have an SQL 2005 database and I know that in the database there is a table which has got some xml strings in it. How can I find this table(s)?

Comment: Is the field a varchar or an xml data type?

Answer (score 5):

If the fields are actually of type XML, then this query will give you what you're looking for:

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where DATA_TYPE = 'XML'
```

Marc

Comment: The field is a varchar. Thats what makes things a bit difficult

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
select 'select distinct ''' || a.name || '.' || b.name 
|| '''  from ' || b.name 
|| 'where ' || b.name || ' like ''%<%/>%'' union ' 
from systable a 
join syscolumns b on (a.id = b.id)
join systypes c on (b.type = c.xtype) 
where a.type ='U' and c.name = ('CHAR', 'CHARN', 'VARCHAR', 'VARCHARN');
```

The first result set will have one row per character column in the database:

select distinct 'table.column' from table where column like '%<%/>%'  union

Take that resultset, snip off the last union, and run the resultset as a SQL statement. It'll bring back the table name and  column name for any column that has one or more rows that look XML-ish.

Edit: this is from memory; the join to systypes and the type names may be wrong, so select from systypes and check.

Comment: Good sultion. Couple of remarks: you'll need '+' instead of '||' in SQL. Also the join should read 'from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on (t.object_id = c.object_id)'

Comment: If you need to be SQL-92 compliant, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of the systable or sys.tables catalog views (those are SQL Server specific)